# mysql database back up every day using java code

Tags: java

Hi we are developed java web application using spring,hibernate and mysql database.I want to take every day mysql database backup instead of taking manually i want it automatically when we run program it should take a backup or when we set time at that time or date it should take backup automatically ..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Don't use java - it's the wrong tool for the job.

Use `cron` (if *nix) or `at` (if windows) for scheduled tasks.

Comment: What about a Java program that is launched by cron or at?

Comment: I agree that Java might be overkill for this task though, mysqladmin + cron should be enough

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has a backup system with a command. Automate it with cron. There's no advantage to involving java.

Comment: thanks a lot but i'm very new to this can u give complete example and how to run that example explain in detail.thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, no. That's not a programming question and generally outside the scope of this site. Try dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: what is cron? ..where should i run that script?can u give some hints.

Comment: http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use a `Thread` to run at a particular time or date, that would do the back up of your database...

**2.** Or make a Java Program, by clicking on which a `thread starts` backing up your database.....

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). According to its documentation:

> Quartz is a full-featured, open source job scheduling service that can
> be integrated with, or used along side virtually any Java EE or Java
> SE application ...largest e-commerce system.
>
> Quartz can be used to create simple or
> complex schedules for executing tens, hundreds, or even
> tens-of-thousands of jobs; jobs whose tasks are defined as standard
> Java components that may execute virtually anything you may program
> them to do. The Quartz Scheduler includes many enterprise-class
> features, such as JTA transactions and clustering.

[Here's an example](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example3) of how you can use the scheduler and cron triggers to schedule a job.